# lstinputlisting breaking when it should not

Tags: floats

I am currently trying to write some text that has tables in it to present the data i need to present, and also has a \lstinputlisting inside that loads a external .txt document that I want to include. Annoyingly the tables tend to clump up on some page that is too far away from the corresponding text. I tried to fix it by having [h] in all tables but that created a problem with \lstinputlisting since now the .txt document is broken between the tables and looks really ugly. Is there a way to not use \lstinputlisting as a float, but still prevent it from breaking on tables, yet keep breaking on page break? Or even have it as a float but keep breaking on pagebreak (since it is longer than 1 page).

Would this work as a MWE?

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{lllllll}
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{lllllll}
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{lllllll}
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{lllllll}
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{lllllll}
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{lllllll}
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{filecontents*}{portableData.txt}
foo
bar
baz
foo
foo\\
foofoo\\
foo\\
foo\\
foo\\
foo\\
foofoo\\
foo\\
foofoo\\
foo\\
foofoo\\
foo\\
foofoo\\
foo\\
foofoo\\
foofoo\\
foo\\
foofoo\\
foo\\
foofoo\\
foofoo\\
foo\\
foofoo\\
foo\\
foo\\
foofoo\\
foofoo\\
foo\\
foofoo\\
foo\\
foofoo\\
foo\\
foo\\
foofoo\\
foo\\
foofoo\\
\\
foofoo\\
foo\\
foofoo\\
foo\\
foofoo\\
foo\\
foofoo\\
foo\\
foo\\
foofoo\\
foo\\
foofoo\\
foo\\
foo\\
foofoo\\
foo\\
foofoo\\

\end{filecontents*}

\lstinputlisting{portableData.txt}

\end{document}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: welcome to TeX.SE! please provide us with a minimal example that reproduces the problem you are facing. see [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/117534)

Comment: @Troy Just edited it. Is this what you had in mind? Tried to keep in line with what the link suggested as far as I understood it.

Comment: Yes, thank you for editing the question, it's much clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest \FloatBarrier from the placeins package together with more relaxed float parameters (https://texfaq.org/FAQ-floats):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{placeins}
 \renewcommand{\topfraction}{.85}
 \renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{.7}
 \renewcommand{\textfraction}{.15}
 \renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{.66}
 \renewcommand{\dbltopfraction}{.66}
 \renewcommand{\dblfloatpagefraction}{.66}
 \setcounter{topnumber}{9}
 \setcounter{bottomnumber}{9}
 \setcounter{totalnumber}{20}
 \setcounter{dbltopnumber}{9}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{lllllll}
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{lllllll}
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{lllllll}
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{lllllll}
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{lllllll}
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{lllllll}
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\FloatBarrier
\begin{filecontents*}{portableData.txt}
foo
bar
baz
foo
foo\\
foofoo\\
foo\\
foo\\
foo\\
foo\\
foofoo\\
foo\\
foofoo\\
foo\\
foofoo\\
foo\\
foofoo\\
foo\\
foofoo\\
foofoo\\
foo\\
foofoo\\
foo\\
foofoo\\
foofoo\\
foo\\
foofoo\\
foo\\
foo\\
foofoo\\
foofoo\\
foo\\
foofoo\\
foo\\
foofoo\\
foo\\
foo\\
foofoo\\
foo\\
foofoo\\
\\
foofoo\\
foo\\
foofoo\\
foo\\
foofoo\\
foo\\
foofoo\\
foo\\
foo\\
foofoo\\
foo\\
foofoo\\
foo\\
foo\\
foofoo\\
foo\\
foofoo\\

\end{filecontents*}

\lstinputlisting{portableData.txt}

\end{document}
```